# Power Query/PowerBi:Table of 2 or more Items appearing together in a transaction

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I'm trying to get a table of Rates of Item Ids occuring together. I have a table in Excel that is a unique list of IDs in rows and across the columns. I then count and divide the Sales Order numbers in which they match and don't match. I'm trying to replicate this in power bi, but I'm still a little to new to pulling it off. I've tried pivoting in a few ways, but I'm not sure i'm on the right path.

Basically going from

Products|Sales Orders

A   | 1

B   | 1

A   | 2

B   |  3

C  | 4

into something like

```
| A |   B |    C |
```

A| 1.0|  0.33 | 0.0

B| 0.33| 1.0  |0.0

C| 0.0 | 0.0   |1.0|

any help is really appreciated

[This is an example of the table I currently use to do this. I'm just counting sales orders that match up with the products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oExLq.png)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion with 3 queries:

1. Table1 (input).
2. OrdersPerProduct: table with unique products and nested lists of their unique orders.
3. Results: resulting in the required output.

Query OrdersPerProduct:

```
let
    Source = Table1,
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Product"}, {{"Orders", each List.Distinct(_[Order]), type list}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

Query Results:

*Note the last step with a dynamic "Change Type" of all Product columns*

```
let
    Source = OrdersPerProduct,
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Source,{"Orders"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "OtherProduct", each #"Removed Columns"[Product], type {text}),
    #"Expanded OtherProduct" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "OtherProduct"),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded OtherProduct",{"Product"},OrdersPerProduct,{"Product"},"ProductOrders",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded ProductOrders" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "ProductOrders", {"Orders"}, {"ProductOrders"}),
    #"Merged Queries1" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded ProductOrders",{"OtherProduct"},OrdersPerProduct,{"Product"},"NewColumn",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded NewColumn" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries1", "NewColumn", {"Orders"}, {"OtherProductOrders"}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded NewColumn", "Rate", each List.Count(List.Intersect({[ProductOrders],[OtherProductOrders]})) / List.Count(List.Distinct(List.Combine({[ProductOrders],[OtherProductOrders]})))),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"ProductOrders", "OtherProductOrders"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns1", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns1"[OtherProduct]), "OtherProduct", "Rate"),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Pivoted Column",List.Transform(#"Pivoted Column"[Product], each {_, type number}))
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Comment: Thank you Marcel, I'm trying your proposed solution now. I'm just trying to follow the logic behind it.

Comment: Well, I faced the same challenge. You can easily copy the code and try with your data, and see step by step what is happening. Just let me know in case you need further clarification.

Comment: Hey @marcel, I'm running itno an expression.error cannot convert value to type list for the Added Custom1. I tried going into the data to change the type like i found [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c6a96479-2376-49a1-a6e6-2bf275eaaa04/power-query-error-expressionerror-we-cannot-convert-the-value-to-type-text?forum=sqlkjpowerpivotforexcel)  but i haven't been able to get it to work. have you ever run into this error?

Comment: Having investigated Power Query for about half a year now, I've seen many errors. In this case, it looks like not all entries in the columns ProductOrders and OtherProductOrders are nested lists. In your input, does each row have a Product (text) and a Sales Order (whole number)?